# Python list character replacement & duplication

Tags: python, list, if-statement, while-loop

I am just beginning to learn Python and want to clean up my code with two things:

1. I am replacing characters in a word with numbers per the list I made. Is there a better way to do that with another *for* or *while* statement?
2. If characters are replaced with the same number twice in a row, I need to keep only the first. How should I remove a duplicate in that case?

```
word = input("Enter a word to code: ")

for ch in range (0, len(word) - 1):

    letters = [('b','f','p','v'), ('c','g','j','k','q','s','x','z'),('d','t'),('l'),('m','n'),('r')]

    for ch in word:
        if ch in letters[0]:
            word = word.replace(ch,"1");
        if ch in letters[1]:
            word = word.replace(ch,"2");
        if ch in letters[2]:
            word = word.replace(ch,"3");
        if ch in letters[3]:
            word = word.replace(ch,"4");
        if ch in letters[4]:
            word = word.replace(ch,"5");
        if ch in letters[5]:
            word = word.replace(ch,"6");
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a mapping dict and use `str.join`:

```
d = {i: n for n, l in enumerate(letters, start=1) for i in l}
''.join(str(d.get(i, i)) for i in 'apple')
```

Output:

```
'a114e'
```

Comment: you should move str conversion from join to dict d